# How to modify the value of an input in spree commerce cart

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, spree

I have the following cart view that i addapted with bootstrap.

```
  <div class="row line_item">

    <div class="col-md-4 cart-item-image" data-hook="cart_item_image">
      <% if variant.images.length == 0 %>
        <%= link_to small_image(variant.product), variant.product %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(variant.images.first.attachment.url(:product)), variant.product %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 cart-item-image" data-hook="cart_item_description">
      <h4><%= link_to line_item.name, product_path(variant.product) %></h4>
      <%= variant.options_text %>
      <% if line_item.insufficient_stock? %>
        <span class="out-of-stock">
          <%= Spree.t(:out_of_stock) %>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
        </span>
      <% end %>
      <span class="line-item-description" data-hook="line_item_description">
        <%= line_item_description_text(line_item.description) %>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 cart-item-price" data-hook="cart_item_price">
      <%= line_item.single_money.to_html %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 cart-item-quantity" data-hook="cart_item_quantity" valign="center">
      <%= item_form.number_field :quantity, min: 0, class: "form-control line_item_quantity", size: 5 %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="cart-item-total" data-hook="cart_item_total">
        <%= line_item.display_amount.to_html unless line_item.quantity.nil? %>
      </div>
      <div class="cart-item-delete" data-hook="cart_item_delete">
        <%= link_to content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign'), '#', class: 'delete', id: "delete_#{dom_id(line_item)}" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the following coffeescript that goes along with it

```
    Spree.ready ($) ->
  if ($ 'form#update-cart').is('*')
    ($ 'form#update-cart a.delete').show().one 'click', ->
      ($ this).parents('.line-item').first().find('input.line_item_quantity').val 0
      ($ this).parents('form').first().submit()
      false

  ($ 'form#update-cart').submit ->
     ($ 'form#update-cart #update-button').attr('disabled', true)
```

Now the delete button does not work with this cart html ( while it is working with the original view a following)

```
<div style="margin-top: 35px;">
  <div class="row">
  <tr class="line-item">
    <td class="col-md-4 cart-item-image" data-hook="cart_item_image">
      <% if variant.images.length == 0 %>
        <%= link_to small_image(variant.product), variant.product %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to image_tag(variant.images.first.attachment.url(:small)), variant.product %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-4 cart-item-description" data-hook="cart_item_description">
      <h4><%= link_to line_item.name, product_path(variant.product) %></h4>
      <%= variant.options_text %>
      <% if line_item.insufficient_stock? %>
        <span class="out-of-stock">
          <%= Spree.t(:out_of_stock) %>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
        </span>
      <% end %>
      <span class="line-item-description" data-hook="line_item_description">
        <%= line_item_description_text(line_item.description) %>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-1 lead text-primary cart-item-price" data-hook="cart_item_price">
      <%= line_item.single_money.to_html %>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-1 cart-item-quantity" data-hook="cart_item_quantity" valign="center">
      <%= item_form.number_field :quantity, min: 0, class: "form-control line_item_quantity", size: 5 %>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-1 lead text-primary cart-item-total" data-hook="cart_item_total">
      <%= line_item.display_amount.to_html unless line_item.quantity.nil? %>
     </td>
    <td class="col-md-1 cart-item-delete" data-hook="cart_item_delete">
      <%= link_to content_tag(:span, '', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign'), '#', class: 'delete', id: "delete_#{dom_id(line_item)}" %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</div>
</div>
```

It seems to me that the coffeescript should work in both cases!

What am i missing after i modify the view ? It seems to me that the coffeescript should perform the search in both cases...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you've done anything wrong when it comes to keeping the markup for the javascript the same.  My guess would be that `Spree.ready ($) ->` isn't actually firing.  That could be caused by you removing javascript files during your view customization by accident.   You should try checking your web developer console to see if there are any javascript errors like Spree not being defined or something like that.